# Visualizing specific information out of two variables in a data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, visualization

Suppose I have this csv file named sample.csv:

```
CODE     AGEGROUP      SEX     CITY      HEALTHSTATUS 
----     ---------     ---     ----      ------------
E101      25 to 29      M      Denver    Recovered
E102      25 to 29      F      Chicago   Recovered
E105      45 to 49      M      Denver    Mild
```

I want to visualize (present in bar graph) the number of people who "recovered" based on their sex (so for the example above, one male and one female recovered).  So far, my code only works in visualizing the number of people based on their sex and health status.

Here's a gist of the code counting the number of occurrences for sex:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 6
plt.style.use("bmh")
fig = plt.figure()

ax0 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
df["SEX"].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=ax0)
ax0.set_xlabel("Sex", fontsize=fs)
ax0.set_ylabel("Number of People", fontsize=fs)
ax0.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=fs)
ax0.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=00)
ax0.set_title("NUMBER OF POSITIVE CASES BY SEX", fontsize=fs)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

What should I do for the program to visualize the number of "recovered" based on sex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
df["SEX"].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=ax0)
```

To:

```
df["SEX"][df['HEALTHSTATUS'] == 'Recovered'].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=ax0)
```

Full Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 6
plt.style.use("bmh")
fig = plt.figure()

ax0 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
df["SEX"][df['HEALTHSTATUS'] == 'Recovered'].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=ax0)
ax0.set_xlabel("Sex", fontsize=fs)
ax0.set_ylabel("Number of People", fontsize=fs)
ax0.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=fs)
ax0.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=00)
ax0.set_title("NUMBER OF POSITIVE CASES BY SEX", fontsize=fs)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If interested, you can play around with pivot table and use the resulting dataframes in your plots.
Some different views of the data:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='SEX', index=['HEALTHSTATUS'],
                    columns=['AGEGROUP'], aggfunc=np.count_nonzero, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='SEX', index=['HEALTHSTATUS'],
                    columns=['AGEGROUP', 'CITY'], aggfunc=np.count_nonzero, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='AGEGROUP', index=['HEALTHSTATUS'],
                    columns='SEX', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df4 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='AGEGROUP', index=['SEX'],
                    columns='HEALTHSTATUS', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
In [234]: df1
Out[234]:
AGEGROUP HEALTHSTATUS  25to29  45to49
0                Mild       0       1
1           Recovered       2       0

In [235]: df2
Out[235]:
AGEGROUP HEALTHSTATUS  25to29        45to49
CITY                  Chicago Denver Denver
0                Mild       0      0      1
1           Recovered       1      1      0

In [236]: df3
Out[236]:
SEX HEALTHSTATUS  F  M
0           Mild  0  1
1      Recovered  1  1

In [237]: df4
Out[237]:
HEALTHSTATUS SEX  Mild  Recovered
0              F     0          1
1              M     1          1
```